# Can't insert url params in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my $resource definition:

```
var Rooms = $resource('/api/social/player/rooms/:roomId', {roomID: '@roomId'});
```

So I want to pass number of messages in room in url parameter to make it look like `/api/social/player/rooms/1?limit=100`

and I'm trying to do this:

```
var selRm = Rooms.get({roomId: 1, limit: 100}, function () {
    // callback body here
}
```

but the url converts to just `/api/social/player/rooms/1`

where am I wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead `get` can you try `query`:

```
var Rooms = $resource('/api/social/player/rooms/:roomId', {roomID: '@roomId''});
```

And the query will be like:

```
var selRm = Rooms.query({roomId: 1, limit: 100}, function () {
    // callback body here
}
```

That should append excess keys as query string parameters:

[Official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) says:

> Each key value in the parameter object is first bound to url template
> if present and then any excess keys are appended to the url search
> query after the ?.
>
> Given a template /path/:verb and parameter {verb:'greet',
> salutation:'Hello'} results in URL /path/greet?salutation=Hello.

Comment: You can improve your answer by showing him a code snippet that uses the .query() call you suggest.

Comment: nope, `Error in resource configuration for action `query`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object (Request: GET /api/social/player/rooms/1)`

Comment: @Compadre: your response should be an array of objects for query.

Comment: I understand this, but I don't want to change my backend to return array where it should return single object, that is ugly and unobvious